# Change element from element host

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, elementhost

I have a `DataGrid` with a few lines:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding mylist}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
   <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Header="x" Binding="{Binding x,UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Header="y" Binding="{Binding y,UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}"></DataGridTextColumn>
   </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

The `DataGrid` sitting as `ElementHost` in two winfrom:

In one window I want to hide a row, how can do this? (Priority to XAML).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved it this way:

I created a property in `ViewModel`

```
    private bool _isVisible=true;

    public bool IsVisible
    {
        get { return _isVisible; }
        set
        {
            _isVisible= value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("IsVisible");
        }
    }
```

When i use the `wpf host control` in my `winfrom` i **init this variable to false**.

I binding the `visibility` column to this property with converter.

and that's all.